# Pasar un array como argumento de una función en Bash

Tags: bash, shell

Estoy usando una variable para contener una lista de opciones a pasar a un programa externo. En un momento dado, tengo que pasar esa variable como argumento de una función de mi *script*, pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo:

```
Iterate( ) {
  for IDX in ${1[@]} ; do
    echo ${IDX}
  done
}

ARGS=('arg1' 'arg2')

echo "${ARGS[@]}"

Iterate ${ARGS}
```

Pero no le gusta demasiado:

> ${1[@]}: bad substitution

- ¿ Como puede pasar un *array* como argumento de una función ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

puedes usar lo siguiente:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
function Iterate() {
   arr=("$@")
   for IDX in "${arr[@]}"; do
        echo "$IDX"
    done
}

array=("arg1" "arg-2" "arg 3")

Iterate "${array[@]}"
```

[image: salida de ejemplo]

Answer (score 1):

Pásaselo por referencia. Es más entendible.

```
#!/bin/bash

get_arr() { 
    declare -n array_param="$1"

    echo "Elementos: ${array_param[@]}"
}

arr1=(a be ce de)
arr2=(uno dos tres cuatro)

get_arr arr1
get_arr arr2
```

Y lo ejecutamos:

```
$ ./array_params.sh
Elementos: a be ce de
Elementos: uno dos tres cuatro
```

De todas maneras, en ninguno de los casos le pasas el array como parametro. Mientras en la respuesta de @LeoLopez, desempaquetas el array enfrente de tu función, y le pasas los elementos separados por un espacio; con mi opción, le pasas el nombre de la variable; ya adentro, el nombre se expande y se le referencia a esa otra variable externa para que pueda ser manipulada indirectamente.